# How can I roughly determine the physical size of a device in javascript or css?

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, responsive-design

I am building a web page which contains svg graphics. I want to make it responsive.

If the page is loaded on a physically small device, i.e. a smart phone, the graphics is too small to be viewed well, so I have to change it in case of a smart phone client.

The exact device or even the exact screen resolution is not important. Important is that I can answer the question "Is the client a small device?".

How can I do that?

Assuming that this is a common question, there should be a best practise for this or a common library. Can you help me?

Comment: i guess you just need to add the meta flags everyone copy+pastes into the top of the page :), so that it scales on mobiles

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: does "device-width" in the meta element have the same value as the variable "screen.width" and does it relate to the media query value "min-device-width"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest doing it like this, putting this tag on the head of your index.html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This will allow you to work with media queries, where you can choose different css style properties depending on the size of the screen. Some examples:

```
@media all and (min-width:1200px){ ... }
@media all and (min-width: 960px) and (max-width: 1199px) { ... }
@media all and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) { ... }
@media all and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px){ ... }
@media all and (max-width: 599px) { ... }
@media all and (max-width: 479px) { ... }
```

There are many other ways to set up the media queries, there is definitely one that is perfect for what you're trying to do.

[W3 media query example](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_mediaqueries_ex1)

[Using media queries by Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Finally, I'd suggest setting the `height, max-height` and `width and max-width` styles with the `vh` and `vw` units, such as:

```
height: 50vh;
width: 50vw;
```

VH and VW stands for viewport height and viewport width. This will make it so an image's size, for example, is exactly half the size of a device screen.